# How to pass the Zoho-oauthtoken in the Header using Guzzle on Laravel?

Tags: laravel, http-headers, guzzle, octobercms, zoho

I have this cURL that I want to convert for Guzzle

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://subscriptions.zoho.com/api/v1/hostedpages/newsubscription",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"{\n    \"plan\": {\n        \"plan_code\": \"AM-001\",\n        \"price\": " . $gPrice . ",\n        \"tax_id\": \"1786305000000842230\",\n    },\n    \"addons\": [\n        {\n            \"addon_code\": \"AB-001\",\n            \"addon_description\": \"Ads Budget\",\n            \"price\": " . $bPrice . ",\n\n        }\n    ],\n    \"coupon_code\": \"150-credit\"\n    \n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "X-com-zoho-subscriptions-organizationid: " . $org_id,
    "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken " . $accessToken,
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  ),
));
```

For now, I have convert this :

```
$headers = [
            'Authorization' => 'Zoho-oauthtoken ' . $access_token,
            'X-com-zoho-subscriptions-organizationid' => $org_id,
        ];

        $res = $client->request('POST', 'https://subscriptions.zoho.com/api/v1/hostedpages/newsubscription', $headers, [
            'plan' => [
                'plan_code' => 'AM-001',
                'price' => $data['finaltotal'],
                'tax_id' => '1786305000000842230',
            ],
            'addons' =>[
                'addon_code' => 'AB-001',
                'addon_description' => 'Ads Budget',
                'price' => $data['finalads']
            ],
            'coupon_code' => '150-credit'
        ]);
```

But I have

"Client error: `POST https://subscriptions.zoho.com/api/v1/hostedpages/newsubscription` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{"code":14,"message":"Invalid value passed for authtoken."}"

Have I correctly defined the header?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

third option is `options` for request, So if you need to pass `headers` you need to specify key `headers`.

so your code should look like this

```php
$options = [
    'headers' => [ // <- here :)
            'Authorization' => 'Zoho-oauthtoken ' . $access_token,
            'X-com-zoho-subscriptions-organizationid' => $org_id,
    ];
]

$res = $client->request(
    'POST',
    'https://subscriptions.zoho.com/api/v1/hostedpages/newsubscription', 
    $options, // <- options
    [
            'plan' => [
                    'plan_code' => 'AM-001',
                    'price' => $data['finaltotal'],
                    'tax_id' => '1786305000000842230',
            ],
            'addons' =>[
                    'addon_code' => 'AB-001',
                    'addon_description' => 'Ads Budget',
                    'price' => $data['finalads']
            ],
            'coupon_code' => '150-credit'
    ]
);
```

try this it should work.

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: It is working for the oauthtoken, now I have another error code 

`` "Client error: `POST https://subscriptions.zoho.com/api/v1/hostedpages/newsubscription` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"code":40002,"message":"The request payload must not be empty for this request."}``

I think I'm going to open a new question for this one or do you have any idea of what is the problem?

I think is with the Addons because in the doc

https://www.zoho.com/subscriptions/api/v1/#Hosted-Pages_Create_a_subscription

Comment: hmm did you set this header ? :) `Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8`